# Directory does not exist, but clearly does

Tags: linux, coldfusion, server, coldfusion-11

I am working on an old Coldfusion 11 application for my company and this error is stumping me. There is the following check inside a `.cfm`:

```
<cffunction name="init">
<cfargument name="searchDir" required="yes" default="#replace(GetDirectoryFromPath(GetCurrentTemplatePath()),'/services','')#xml/">
    <cfargument name="checkoutMode" required="no" default="protect">

    <!--- library variables initialization --->
    <cfset Variables.libBaseDir = arguments.searchDir>
    <cfset Variables.libCheckoutMode = arguments.checkoutMode>


    <cfif NOT DirectoryExists(Variables.libBaseDir)>
        <cfthrow message="The base document directory '#Variables.libBaseDir#' does not exist!">
    </cfif>
    ....
</cffunction>
```

`Variable.libBaseDir` is printed in the error message as:

```
/opt/app/coldfusion/coldfusion11/cfusion/wwwroot/<some-app>/xml/
```

But my directory is clearly as follows (used `pwd`):

```
/opt/app/coldfusion/coldfusion11/cfusion/wwwroot/<some-app>/xml
```

**This works on a Windows server, but not Linux**, my sole purpose of doing this.

Any ideas why this would throw the error, thanks.

Comment: there's a replace backslash services in the CF code. Would not work under linux...

Comment: You're saying I need to use such a service? Or a that service won't work?

Comment: The forward slash after xml does not appear in your pwd output.

Comment: I tried that as well, removed it from the end of the line, no luck. And my mistake I had previously fixed the back slashes to forward slashes, I copied wrong, they are currently forward slashes. Edited the post.

Comment: I am not running Linux, but out of curiosity, does it fail with *all* directories, or just some of them?

Comment: It gets to that one (assuming its the first) and fails, so I think it will most likely fail with all of them.

Comment: What happens if you use the correct path directly in `DirectoryExists()`?

Comment: It works... then the application actually runs. So it is as if the directory is built correctly, but the `DirectoryExists()` incorrectly stops the program by throwing the error.

Comment: Mixing back-/forwardslashes doesn't matter with CF's IO functions. But did you check the permissions in the specified path? Are you able to access other folders in the area?

Comment: try using 
`#replace(GetDirectoryFromPath(ExpandPath( "./" )),'/services','')#xml/`
instead
`#replace(GetDirectoryFromPath(GetCurrentTemplatePath()),'/services','')#xml/`
let me now if it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I ended up using because a "/" continued to be appended to the end of the path no matter what I did.

```
<cfargument name="searchDir" required="yes" default="#replace(GetDirectoryFromPath(GetCurrentTemplatePath()),'services/','xml')#">

<cfset Variables.libBaseDir = Left(arguments.searchDir, Len(arguments.searchDir)-1)>
```

So I removed the "/" at the end of the path and that fixed it.

Thanks for the all previous suggestions.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what flavor of linux? I ran a few hard coded tests in Ubuntu and it worked fine for me, with or without the trailing "/".